# How to plot a greek letter on a 3D plot label with hist3D()?

Tags: r, plot3d

I am plotting a 3D histogram using `hist3D()`, and want to change `xlab` so that it includes a Greek letter with a subscript.

I used

```
xlab=expression(theta[1]).
```

It doesn't work, and I just get the string "theta[1]" in the label. It works fine, on the other hand, for just the regular plot command.

So how can I introduce subscripted Greek letters to `hist3D()` plots?

(`hist3D()` is in the plot3D library)

Comment: you should add a reproducible example and mention which package are you using.

Comment: The function `hist3D` calls the function `persp`. From `?persp`, concerning `xlab`: `These must be character strings; expressions are not accepted.`

Answer (score 3):

The `hist3D`function does not accept expressions for axis labels. One workaround is to use the Unicode character for theta, θ.

```
# example data
library(plot3D)
x <- seq(-pi, pi, by = 0.2)
y <- seq(-pi, pi, by = 0.3)
grid <- mesh(x, y)
z <- with(grid, cos(x) * sin(y))

hist3D(z = z, x = x, y = y, border = "black", xlab = "θ1")
```

This displays a theta symbol but no subscript 1.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround is to use `text3D` function from the same `plot3D` package. It accepts the math expressions as labels so we can write as usual  `expression(theta[1])`. The only minor issue in this workaround is to find the suitable coordinates of our label

```
# example data
library(plot3D)
x <- seq(-pi, pi, by = 0.2)
y <- seq(-pi, pi, by = 0.3)
grid <- mesh(x, y)
z <- with(grid, cos(x) * sin(y))

hist3D(z = z, x = x, y = y, border = "black", ticktype = "detailed", xlab = "", ylab="y", zlab="z")
text3D(2, -5, 0, labels = expression(theta[1]), add = TRUE, adj = 1)
```

I have found that `2,-5,0` are quite good for this example. The label is not rotated one as in case of the regular labels.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use `scatterplot3d`:

[image]

```
z <- seq(-10, 10, 0.01)
x <- cos(z)+1
y <- sin(z)+1
scatterplot3d(volcano, highlight.3d=TRUE, col.axis="blue",
                            col.grid="gray", main="scatterplot-greeks", pch=21,
                            xlab=expression(theta[1]),
                            ylab=expression(beta[2]),
                            zlab=expression(alpha[3]),cex.lab=1.5)
```

Comment: I like persp much better, it plots things nicer than this... but thanks.